# Read a single value from MySQL MAX() statement with php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to read out the highest number of a column in my table. I try to do it with MAX() like this:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(msgconv) FROM msg");

if ( false===$stmt ) {
  die('prepare() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($conn->error));
}

$stmt->execute();

$conv_highest = $stmt->get_result();

echo $conv_highest;

$stmt->close();
```

I tryed it with `fetch_assoc();` aswell, but I don´t get any value into my php-variable.

**EDIT:**

```
$row = $conv_highest->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['msgconv'];
```

Sadly that doesn´t work either. Can somebody help me please?

Comment: what is the column type for `msgconv`? and the entire schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your edit has got you most of the way there. The reason it doesn't work is that the field in the table is not called `msgconv`; you have selected `MAX(msgconv)` in your query so the value in `$row` you are looking for is `$row['MAX(msgconv)']`. So you have a few options, you can

```
$row = $conv_highest->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['MAX(msgconv)'];
```

or you could change the query to:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT MAX(msgconv) AS msgconv FROM msg");
// ...
$row = $conv_highest->fetch_assoc();
echo $row['msgconv'];
```

or you could leave the query as is and fetch a numeric array e.g.

```
$row = $conv_highest->fetch_row();
echo $row[0];
```

Comment: this is the correct answer, the answer above doesn't even warrant an upvote because its wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Usually in php you can not echo an object or an array the method get_result returns a result set so you will have to iterate or open the object and get the values inside. See this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.get-result.php) for more information. try to put $conv_highest in a print_r it may help you look inside the object e.g print_r($conv_highest). The solution might look like this

```
SELECT MAX(msgconv) as maximum FROM msg
      while ($row = $conv_highest->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo 'Highest: '.$row['maximum'].'<br>';
   }
```

Comment: Thank you for your replay. 
I get this back:

mysqli_result Object ( [current_field] => 0 [field_count] => 1 [lengths] => [num_rows] => 1 [type] => 0 )

But now, whats irritating me is, that there is nowhere the highest number of that field "msgconv".

Comment: Okay, now i get it halfway... Is there no other way to get the result if there is only one value?

Comment: try and check my edited answer hopefully that can help, or it may give you a hint on how to solve your problem

Comment: @LucksonMakuSimz I edited your answer since it contained an obvious space in the column array's name `$row['maximum']`, which was `$row['maximum ']`. Please be more careful :-) That would have thrown them an undefined index notice without their knowing.

Comment: @LucksonMakuSimz you're welcome. Btw, best to ping someone back when it's meant for a person in particular. I only saw your comment above because I was still in the question. Using `@member name` as I did for you, will notify that person in particular. *Cheers*